# Uniformly distributed subsequence

Tags: uniform-distribution, ergodic-theory

Let $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers uniformly distributed mod 1. 
If $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ where the limit $$d(E)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}|\{1, 2, \dots, N\}\cap E|$$ exists and positive, then is it true that the subsequence $(x_{n})_{n\in E}$ is also uniformly distributed? 
Clearly it is true for $x_{n}=n\alpha$ and $E=m\mathbb{N}$ where $\alpha$ is irrational number and $m\in \mathbb{N}$. I tried to show this by using Weyl's criterion, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Do you demand the limit be positive?

Comment: @AdamHughes Oh sure. I omitted it. Thanks!

Comment: For your example $x_n=n\alpha$, if we consider the set $E=\{n:n\alpha\in [0,1) \mod 1\}$ for example. It is of positive density but $(x_n)_{n\in E}$ is not uniformly distributed in $[0,1) \mod 1$.

Comment: @SimingTu Maybe $E=\{n:n\alpha\in [0, 1/2) mod 1\}$, right? Thanks!

Comment: @See-Woo Lee Yes, you are right. Sorry for the mistake.